# AngularJS Broadcast confusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a question regarding broadcasting to children scope objects. I have the following factory:

```
app.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
var sharedService = {};

sharedService.alertArray = [];

sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(alertArray) {
    this.alertArray = alertArray;
    this.broadcastItem();
};

sharedService.broadcastItem = function () {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
};

return sharedService;
});
```

Here is a snippet of my parent controller:

```
app.controller('CreateController', function ($scope, mySharedService) {

mySharedService.prepForBroadcast($scope.alerts);

});
```

And here is a snippet of my child controller:

```
app.controller('ListController', function ($scope, mySharedService) {

$scope.alerts = [];

$scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function () {
    $scope.alerts = mySharedService.alertArray;
});

});
```

I also inject the following broadcasting objects into my controllers:

```
ListController.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];
CreateController.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];
```

**My Question:**
When the broadcastItem method is called from the parent controller, it initalizes the array just fine, but the handleBroadcast method within $scope.$on is never called. I thought this method should be invoked by the $rootScope.$broadcast within the factory? Is there anything i'm missing on this?

Comment: You might want to use https://github.com/georapbox/angular-PubSub angular module !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might happen because parent controller calls service before child controller finished to load. Try to add dummy timeout:

```
 $timeout(function () {
   mySharedService.prepForBroadcast($scope.alerts);
 }, 0);
```

Working example:

**JS**

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1010/)**</kbd>

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

function ParentCtrl($scope, $timeout, mySharedService) {

    console.log('firstCtrl');

    $scope.alerts = "Im alert";

     $timeout(function () {
       mySharedService.prepForBroadcast($scope.alerts);
    }, 0);    


}

function ChildCtrl($scope, mySharedService) {

     console.log('secondCtrl');

    $scope.alerts = [];

$scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function () {



    $scope.alerts = mySharedService.alertArray;
});
}

app.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
var sharedService = {};

sharedService.alertArray = [];

sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(alertArray) {
    this.alertArray = alertArray;
    this.broadcastItem();
};

sharedService.broadcastItem = function () {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
};

return sharedService;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl"> 
        <pre>{{alerts}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```