# What is functionality of zeroed $timeout in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sometimes to make to code to work we use *zeroed* $timeout:

```
$timeout(function () {
    /* some stuff goes here */
  }, 0);
```

We use it in controllers, directive links ....

I try to understand what aforementioned rows give us and found that is something like mutex that pauses digest cycle till all modules will load.

This is [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624285/angularjs-broadcast-confusion/21624423#21624423) (answered by @Maxim) that demonstrates this problem

Can somebody spread a light on this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular's `$timeout` is basically a pretty API over `setTimeout`. 
JavaScript is an asynchronous, event-based language so `setTimeout` does not stop execution, it just basically tells the browser

"Please run this piece of code after X seconds, but until then keep executing whatever code follows"

The last part of that statement is always respected, even if the *timeout* is 0.

So what happens is that the code in the function you pass to `$timeout` executes *after* every other piece of code following the call to `$timeout` is executed.

Comment: One reason it's useful was described by Royi Namir in his answer.

Comment: So with timeout I just level down execution priority , right?

Comment: With a 0 timeout, yes.

Comment: But please don't use this as a general architectural mechanism in your apps. It leads to some pretty hard to understand code. Only use it when there is no other choice. You'll know when it's the case.

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to NG.

It's related to the fact that you want the browser to do other things between.

otherwise - the browser might be stuck.

It's a trick to tell the browser : " I know you're busy - and therefore - dont forget me and do this as soon as possible"

Comment: Even if timeout 0? thanks. please see the link I posted. Without o timeout the example doesn't work

Comment: @fessy Yes. _You want to break a long-running loop or calculation into smaller components so that the browser doesn't appear to 'freeze' or say "Script on page is busy"._